# Error with tweepy API posting text with update_status

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, automated-tests, tweepy

I am working on a Python based twitter bot using tweepy that uses speedtest-cli and subprocess to get my internet speed and tweet at my ISP every 45 minutes if it is underneath what we pay for, however, I am having a problem. For testing, I made 2 files, both identical in imports and both in Python 2.7 using Python 3 print function. One has a static, set speedtest result as to allow me to test the Tweepy aspect, while the other runs the speedtest and writes it to an identically named variable.

The real version is

```
while True:
testresraw = subprocess.check_output('speedtest --no-upload', shell=True) #Test speed and get output
testresnone,testressplit = testresraw.split('Download: ')#Remove text before the download speed
testresint,testresnone = testressplit.split('Mbit/s')#Remove text after download speed
float(testresint)#Make sure download speed is a number
if testresint<float(10.0):
    statustext= ('My download speed is currently %d MB/s, which is less than the 10 we pay @CenturyLink for' % (testresint))
    api.update_status(status=statustext)
    time.sleep(2700)
else:
    time.sleep(2700)
```

And the testing version is

```
testresint = 1
if testresint<float(10.0):
    statustext = ('My download speed is currently %d MB/s, which is less than the 10 we pay @CenturyLink for' % (testresint))
    api.update_status(status=statustext)
    time.sleep(2700)
else:
    time.sleep(2700)
```

Only the testing version works and I can't figure out why.

EDIT: I placed some `print` functions to show me where it was messing up, and as it turns out, it is going to the `else` statement after judging that `testresint` is not less than 10, mistakenly. I removed the `float` before the 10.0 as advised. I still can't figure out what's gone wrong.

Comment: You are resetting `testresnone` in `testresint,testresnone = testressplit.split('Mbit/s')`. Is that correct? Also, Calling `float()` on `10.0` is not needed.

Comment: Yes, `testresnone` is a placeholder to allow me to only take only the parts I need of the output from the subprocess, and thank you.

Comment: In the previous statement, you assigned `testresraw.split('Download: ')[0]` to `testresnone` and then you changed it to `testressplit.split('Mbit/s')[1]`, so I was wondering if that was necessary.

Comment: Yes, in order to have something to make sure that it's not split into a list but instead 2 separate strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by changing `if testresint<float(10.0)` to `if float(testresint)<float(10.0)`.